# How to use new rows with formulas and be seen as empty

Tags: google-sheets

I'm sending data to Google sheets from a software. Each new client the google sheets is filled with the clients data. The thing is, everytime I have a new row, I would like to insert data into a column that has a formula (ID column). But since you have a formula in that cell (or column using arrayfilter), google sheets assumes that the row is not empty and inserts the data into the next one.

Like this:

New client | Jony | Phone | E-mail | ID (formula that checks for e-mail and returns a value)

If I drag the formula to calculate each new client the right ID, the new client data will not be pasted into the next row because you have an "ID column with a formula" and it is seen as "row not empty."

If I use this formulas as they are, the next new row will be the number 1001 at the end of the page.

Comment: An example sheet would help, could you provide one?

Comment: Can you please post an example of the code that adds a new row?

Comment: Added. I hope you guys can understand more clearly :)

Comment: I cannot see the code you are using to add the rows. Maybe you can describe how the new rows are added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
Basically I created a second sheet using ArrayFormula to copy the original columns from sheet 1 and in this second sheet I added the formulas I wanted and everything works fine :)